# Javascript not changing <img> src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I've been looking through StackOverflow for an hour now and I;m still not sure what I'm missing here. I'm pretty new to JavaScript so it's probably something obvious, but I can't seem to find any answers online.

This is my HTML:

```
<body id="body" onclick="pageClick()">
    <img class="overlay" id="overlay1" src="images/empty.png">
</body>
```

and this is my JavaScript:

```
function pageClick() {
    document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.getElementsById("overlay1").src = "images/banned.png";
}
```

I included the body background color to show myself that the script is running, yet the source attribute is not changing. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: its element not elements,  getElementsById("overlay1") should be getElementById("overlay1")

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic because this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  document.getElementById instead  document.getElement**s**ById

Answer (score 1):

It's `getElementById`, you wrote `getElementsById`.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `querySelector` too

```
function pageClick() {
    document.querySelector("#body").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    document.querySelector(".overlay1").src = "images/banned.png";
}
```